# Discount distribution problem (optimization)

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

Suppose we have a shop and sell **5** different products: **A, B, C, D** and **E.**
Each product has a fixed base cost of $8.00.

Now we represent the amount of each product bought as a tuple **(a, b, c, d, e)**. These are the rules for discounts:

- 1 different item only (e.g. **(1,0,0,0,0)** or **(0,22,0,0,0)**): **0%**
- 2 different items (e.g. **(1,2,0,0,0)**): **5%**
- 3 different items (e.g. **(0,2,3,1,0)**): **10%**
- 4 different items: **20%**
- 5 different items: **25%**

As an example, say we have **(2,0,3,1,5)**, so 2x Product A, 3x Product C, 1x ProductD, 5x Product E.
Then for example we could use a **greedy** approach:

```
(2,0,3,1,5) -> (1,0,2,0,4) -> (0,0,1,0,3) -> (0,0,0,0,2) -> (0,0,0,0,1) -> (0,0,0,0,0)

          (-20%)         (-10%)          (-5%)         (-0%)          (-0%)
```

The discount can only be applied once per group of different products. In the first step we would apply it to 4 different products, so **($8.00 * 4) * 0.8**, second step we would get **($8.00 * 3) * 0.90.**

So if we introduce variables in then we get in general that

```
totalPrice = [(base_price * n) * discountFor(n)] + [(base_price * (n-1)) * discountFor(n-1)] + ... + [(base_price * 2) * discountFor(2)] + (k * base_price)
```

I'm not allowed to use a naive approach. Playing with a few examples I found the greedy approach to be pretty stable but I'm not sure if there's a counterexample.

I tried writing the problem down formally but there's no obvious analytical solution here as the number
of how often we could use a specific discount is dependent on which ones we have used before.

Is there a way to solve this using dynamic programming, linear programming or another problem-solving technique?

Comment: What do you want to minimize/maximize ?

Comment: I want to minimize the total price using the best discount distribution.

Comment: I did not get the whole parameters of the problem, but it seems that dynamic programming would be the way to go for it. Your memoisation array would be a 5D array, and as long as the number of items is relatively small the approach would be tractable.

Comment: You are over-thinking this problem.  You didn't state it in the verbiage, but it appears you can only increment in steps of 1 in each product area.  So, unless there is some kind of inverted discount structure, a greedy approach is easy and best.

Comment: Try to use recursive method for solving. only programming method comes into my mind by looking at your problem is that.